# Uploading a h5py file to aws and downloading it again

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, h5py

I have not been able to find a clear solution so hopefully this question can be of use to others in the future.

Basically I am creating a h5py object as follows:

```
keys_d = [matrix_l2T.data, matrix_l2T.indices, matrix_l2T.indptr]
keys_n = ['data', 'indices', 'indptr' ]
file_to_save = h5py.File(FILENAME)
for i,j in zip(keys_n, keys_d):
    file_to_save.create_dataset(i, data = j)
```

Uploading to AWS as follows:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file(Filename = FILENAME, Key = KEY, Bucket = BUCKET)
```

Downloading as follows:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
try:
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, FILENAME) except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
    print("The object does not exist.")
else:
    raise
```

Then I have tried to open this file in a variety of ways but it does not seem to be performed without an error.

I have tried:

```
h5py.File(FILENAME,'r')
```

And i got:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (bad object header version number)
```

I tried also:

```
with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
   a = f.read()
```

I need the rb because without it I get 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte. The last piece of code returns binary code not really sure what I should do next.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but it looks like the `aws` load and download has corrupted your file, possibly by adding some sort of header byte(s).  Does `aws` have a special way of handling binary files (as opposed to text), which shouldn't be modified in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I wasn't closing the h5py file. One needs to add

```
file_to_save.close()
```

before uploading to aws